# Export JSON to CSV with Headers using JQ

Tags: text-processing, csv, json, jq

I have a (dictionary?) JSON file, similar to:

```
{
  "Salad": {
    "name": "Dressing",
    "good": true,
    "status": true
  },
  "Data_XML": {
    "name": "XML",
    "good": false
  },
  "Functionality": {
    "name": "FUNC",
    "good": true
  },
  "Data_JSON": {
    "name": "JSON",
    "good": true,
    "status": false
  }
}
```

I am looking for a CSV output like this:

```
"title","good","name","status"
"Salad",true,"Dressing",true
"Data_XML",false,"XML",""
"Functionality",true,"FUNC",""
"Data_JSON",true,"JSON",false
```

What [I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960857/how-to-convert-arbirtrary-simple-json-to-csv-using-jq) and used so far is this...

```
jq -r '(map(keys_unsorted) | add | unique) as $cols | $cols, map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.]))[] | @csv'
```

Output:

```
"good","name","status"
true,"Dressing",true
false,"XML",
true,"FUNC",
true,"JSON",false
```

I would need the equivalent of **Salad, Data_XML, Functionality and Data_JSON** as the ***FIRST COLUMN*** (unsorted) along with the related data.

As for the ***"good","name","status"*** these would be the Header fields and as such would need to be dynamically retrieved as they're random (each data set may have 4 and others as much as 10). It's a relatively large file and would be hard to parse these by hand, leaving the "title" as the first column header item. ***"title","good","name","status","something","else","random","etc"***

I feel I am so close... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this will work :

```
jq  -r '["title","name","good","status"],(to_entries|.[]|  
        [.key,.value.good,.value.name,
          (if .value.status == null then "" else .value.status end )]
        )|@csv'
```

New version more generic

```
jq -r ' to_entries as $row | 
  ( ( map(keys_unsorted ) | add | unique ) as $cols |
    ( ["title" , $cols] | flatten) , 
  ( $row | .[] as $onerow | $onerow | 
       ( [ .key , ( $cols |   
           map ($onerow.value[.] as $v | if $v == null then "" else $v end )  ) ] 
         | flatten ) ) ) | @csv '
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks @EchoMike444. That works for defined / known string/keys, but is there a dynamic approach?

Comment: What I have come up wtih so far is `["key",(map(keys_unsorted) | add | unique)[]],(to_entries | .[] | [.key,.value.good,.value.name,.value.status]) | @csv`. I need the last part `[.key,.value.good,.value.name,.value.status]` to fetch the keys dynamically. Any thoughts?

Comment: I now have the reverse... `["Title",(map(keys_unsorted) | add | unique)[]] as $cols | $cols, map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.]))[] | @csv`. ugh. Just need to get this mashed together. I feel like I am so close (albeit, not elegant).

Comment: GENIUS! Thanks again @EchoMike444! This works perfectly! (Proof: https://jqplay.org/s/x7YZoq-YnO )  

PS. Typo $oner.value -> $onerow.value

Comment: After exporting the JSON data to CSV, and editing the details in Excel, is there a relatively easy way to export it back to a JSON file?

Comment: I'd suggest posting a new question and linking it here.