# Convert JSON of arrays to CSV with headers using JQ

Tags: text-processing, csv, json, jq

I am getting Json as column ID and arrays -

```
  {
      "ObjectID": [
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
      ],
      "Name": [
        "Apple",
        "Orange",
        "Grape",
        "Banana",
        "Jackfruit"
      ],
      "Color": [
        "Red",
        "Orange",
        "Green",
        "Yellow",
        "null"
      ],
      "Acidity": [
        3.9,
        3.5,
        2.99,
        6,
        5.0
      ]
    }
```

I am trying to convert it using jq to to a plain CSV format like -

```
ObjectID,Name,Color,Acidity
0,Apple,Red,3.9
1,Orange,Orange,3.5
2,Grape,Green,2.99
3,Banana,Yellow,6
4,Jackfruit,null,5.0
```

Question related to [Export JSON to CSV with Headers using JQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453343/export-json-to-csv-with-headers-using-jq)  . Looking for preferably a generic answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question after playing with given answers, generic solution for json arrays

```
jq --raw-output 'to_entries|map(.key),(map(.value)|transpose[])|@csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using the `transpose` function:

```
<file jq -r '(to_entries|map(.key)),([.ObjectID,.Name,.Color,.Acidity]|transpose|.[])|@csv'
```

The object name is extracted using `to_entries|map(.key)`.

The object content is put inside an array and `transpose`d in order to get arrays with element of each object.

The result is then going through the `@csv` operator that converts the array into a comma separated string.